# AWS sagemaker RandomCutForest (RCF) vs scikit lean RandomForest (RF)?

Tags: classification, random-forest, decision-tree, amazon-sagemaker

Is there a difference between the two, or are they different names for the same algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RandomCutForest (RCF) is an unsupervised method primarily used for anomaly detection, while RandomForest (RF) is a supervised method that can be used for regression or classification.

For RCF, see documentation ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html)) and notebook example ([here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb))