# Randomforest in amazon aws sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, random-forest, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking to recreate a randomforest model built locally, and deploy it through sagemaker. The model is very basic, but for comparison I would like to use the same in sagemaker. I don't see randomforest among sagemaker's built in algorithms (which seems weird) - is my only option to go the route of [deploying my own custom model](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/train-and-host-scikit-learn-models-in-amazon-sagemaker-by-building-a-scikit-docker-container/)? Still learning about containers, and it seems like a lot of work for something that is just a simple randomforestclassifier() call locally. I just want to baseline against the out of the box randomforest model, and show that it works the same when deployed through AWS sagemaker.

Comment: A random forest demo was just added to the SageMaker demo repo https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*edit 03/30/2020: adding a link to the the [SageMaker Sklearn random forest demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb)*

in SageMaker you have 3 options to write scientific code:

- **Built-in algorithms**
- **Open-source pre-written containers** (available
  for sklearn, tensorflow, pytorch, mxnet, chainer. Keras can be
  written in the tensorflow and mxnet containers)
- **Bring your own container** (for R for example)

**At the time of writing this post there is no random forest classifier nor regressor in the built-in library**. There is an algorithm called [Random Cut Forest](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-built-in-amazon-sagemaker-random-cut-forest-algorithm-for-anomaly-detection/) in the built-in library but it is an unsupervised algorithm for anomaly detection, a different use-case than the [scikit-learn random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) used in a supervised fashion (also [answered in StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56728230/aws-sagemaker-randomcutforest-rcf-vs-scikit-lean-randomforest-rf?noredirect=1&lq=1)). But it is easy to use the open-source pre-written scikit-learn container to implement your own. There is a [demo showing how to use Sklearn's random forest in SageMaker](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb), with training orchestration bother from the high-level SDK and `boto3`. You can also use this other [public sklearn-on-sagemaker demo](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/Scikit-learn%20Estimator%20Example%20With%20Batch%20Transform.ipynb) and change the model. A benefit of the pre-written containers over the "Bring your own" option is that the dockerfile is already written, and web serving stack too.

Regarding your surprise that Random Forest is not featured in the built-in algos, the library and its 18 algos already cover a rich set of use-cases. For example for supervised learning over structured data (the usual use-case for the random forest), if you want to stick to the built-ins, depending on your priorities (accuracy, inference latency, training scale, costs...) you can use SageMaker XGBoost (XGBoost has been winning tons of datamining competitions - every winning team in the top10 of the KDDcup 2015 used XGBoost [according to the XGBoost paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf) - and scales well) and linear learner, which is extremely fast at inference and can be trained at scale, in mini-batch fashion over GPU(s). [Factorization Machines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/fact-machines-howitworks.html) (linear + 2nd degree interaction with weights being column embedding dot-products) and [SageMaker kNN](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-supports-knn-classification-and-regression/) are other options. Also, things are not frozen in stone, and the list of built-in algorithms is being improved fast.

Comment: and a random forest demo was just added to the SageMaker demo repo https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_randomforest/Sklearn_on_SageMaker_end2end.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

RandomForestClassifier is not supported out of the box with SageMaker, but [XGBoost (gradient boosted trees)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html) as well as [`decisionTreeClassifier` from scikit-learn](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-adds-scikit-learn-support/) are both supported. You can access scikit-learn's `decisionTreeClassifier()` directly from the SageMaker SDK.

Here's a notebook demonstrating use of a `decisionTreeClassifier` from [SageMaker's built-in scikit-learn.](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/scikit_learn_iris/Scikit-learn%20Estimator%20Example%20With%20Batch%20Transform.ipynb)

Deploying your own custom model via a Dockerfile is certainly possible as well (and can seem daunting at first, but isn't all that bad), but I agree in that it wouldn't be ideal for a simple algorithm that's already included in SageMaker :)

---

Edit: Mixed up Random Forest and Random Cut Forest in the original answer as discussed in comment. **Random Cut Forest** algorithm docs for SageMaker are available here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html

Random Cut Forest (RCF) Jupyter noetbook ex: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/random_cut_forest/random_cut_forest.ipynb

Comment: So I was asking about random cut forest model, but someone said it's different from random forest (unsupervised vs supervised learning) -https://stackoverflow.com/a/56738324/4458718 . So it looks like they are two very different algos?

Comment: Oops - you're correct, my apologies. Random Cut Forest is for unsupervised anomaly detection, whereas Random Forest is an ensemble of decision trees for classification/regression. Are you set on random forest, or are you willing to use xgboost (which is a SageMaker built-in algo) for gradient boosted trees? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/xgboost.html

Comment: @LXandor added additional options for xgboost and `decisionTreeClassifier`, both of which are SageMaker built-ins

Comment: I will be using xgboost eventually, but I wanted to use randomforest to baseline against. So the only way to get randomforest is by going through the custom model docker file process? Seems weird, RF is such a popular alogrithm